# git с чистого листа

Tags: git

Хочу загрузить последние изменения и начать работу.
Сделал *git pull*, но после этого *git status* показывает *Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 15 commits*

Как избавиться от этих коммитов? Я хочу просто получить последнюю версию и работать.

Comment: `git push` - отправить ваши коммиты. Если хотите жестко откатиться к ориджину, то - `git reset --hard origin/develop`. Я подозреваю что вы подтянули изменения из одной ветки и переключились на другую? или все 15 коммитов ваши?

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, предвижу следующий вопрос: "я сделал `git reset --hard origin/develop`, и все изменения, которые я сделал, пропали"

Comment: Там нет моих изменений ещё, он добавил эти коммиты после pull'а, я делал reset --hard он пишет что я в последней ветке теперь, но git status по прежнему показывает our branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 15 commits

Comment: @insolor, зато точно будет с чистого листа )) и сразу будет понимание как что работает

Comment: @РусланРуслан это не «он» коммиты добавил, это ваши 15 коммитов. То есть поверх того, что есть в `origin/master` у вас ещё 15 коммитов новых.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ладно представим что это у меня новые коммиты, и мне на них плевать, как мне загрузить последнюю версию с репозитория?

Comment: @РусланРуслан тогда сделайте бэкап (`git branch backup`) на всякий случай и действуйте, как советует Артём. (`git reset --hard origin/master`).

Comment: @РусланРуслан смысл в том, что именно *загружать* изменения не нужно — вы их уже загрузили с помощью `git pull` и они доступны в `origin/master`.